# Precise decay of solution fo fractional Schroedinger equations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fractional-calculus, semi-linear-elliptic-pdes

Let us consider the time-independent fractional Schroedinger equation $$(-\Delta)^s u + u = \vert u \vert^{p-1}u$$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$, where $0<s<1$, $N>2s$ and $1<p<\frac{N+2s}{N-2s}$.
It is known (see Proposition 3.1(ii) of
*Frank, Rupert L.; Lenzmann, Enno; Silvestre, Luis*, [**Uniqueness of radial solutions for the fractional Laplacian**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cpa.21591), Commun. Pure Appl. Math. 69, No. 9, 1671-1726 (2016). [ZBL1365.35206](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1365.35206).) that for any solution $Q \in H^s(\mathbb{R}^N)$ an estimate like $$\left\vert Q(x) + \nabla Q(x) \right\vert \leq \frac{C}{1+\vert x \vert^{N+2s}}$$ holds at infinity. It is however known that $$\left(1+\vert x \vert^{N+2s} \right) Q(x)$$ remains bounded from above *and* from below at infinity.

My question is: is it true that also $$\left(1+\vert x \vert^{N+2s} \right) \nabla Q(x)$$ remains bounded from above *and* from below at infinity? In other words, is $$\frac{C}{1+\vert x \vert^{N+2s}}$$ the *precise* decay at infinity for the derivatives of $Q$?

The missing detail in the literature I have read so far is the bound from below. This sounds strange to me, since I would expect that the derivatives of $Q$ could not decay much faster than $Q$ itself. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I think Prop. 3.1(ii) only gives bounds for $Q$, not $\nabla Q$. Also, a natural guess would be $|\nabla Q(x)| \approx C / |x|^{N+2s+1}$ for large $|x|$, I suppose.